# How to implement settings in admin?

Tags: django

I have Django project with my own app. This app has only two models. I need configure some options specific for this app, but in default Django admin panel.

I was thinking to create a model for example: `SettingsApp` and create one entry with my settings, but in admin panel, user can be add other entries or delete existing entry and app will not work. How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to add your model to be displayed in admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at:

https://github.com/jqb/django-settings

and check if it fits well for you.

Answer (score 0):

This work for my settings model:

```
class SettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_remove_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at application **django-livesettings** from [here](https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-livesettings). As said in [documentation](http://django-livesettings.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

> Django-Livesettings is a project split from the Satchmo Project. It
>   provides the ability to configure settings via an admin interface,
>   rather than by editing settings.py. In addition, livesettings allows
>   you to set sane defaults so that your site can be perfectly functional
>   without any changes. Livesettings uses caching to make sure this has
>   minimal impact on your site’s performance.
>
> Finally, if you wish to lock down your site and disable the settings,
>   you can export your livesettings and store them in your settings.py.
>   This allows you have flexibility in deciding how various users
>   interact with your app.
>
> Livesettings supports several types of input choices:
>
> - Boolean
> - Decimal
> - Duration
> - Float
> - Integer
> - Positive Integer
> - String
> - Long string
> - Multiple strings
> - Long multiple strings
> - Module values
> - Password
>
> Livesettings has been used for many years in the satchmo project and
>   is considered stable and production ready.